# Want to know the local IP address assigned to me by my ISP

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp, ip-address

I use a TP-Link router (3420) to connect to my ISP.

My local IP address is 192.168.0.22. The ISP uses DHCP and the router shows the range of it 10.19.xxx.xxx. Sites like whatismyip.com show the external IP address as 103.50.xxx.xxx.

I do ipconfig and get my local IP. I go to google or whatismyip.com and it shows the external IP.

But the IP the ISP (10.19.xxx.xxx) uses can only be seen in the router status page.

Can it be viewed without logging into the router? How?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your ISP is using CGN to assign you a private address (`10.19.xxx.xxx`). What the world sees is that ISP's NAT address (`103.50.xxx.xxx`). You assign the local addresses. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: This is the address which will help me to control the router remotely.

Comment: @Karim - Given your how your ISP assigns IP Address controlling your router remotely is unlikely to be possible.  The IP address your actually being assigned, is a NAT address which isn't accessible outside of your network, and cannot be reached remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a host name on the IP address and see if it has a hostname that appears it is owned by your ISP. You could also look up the IP address and see if it belongs to a block of IP addresses assigned to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your computer by External IP. because your ISP using Carrier-Grad NAT technology. The IP assigned to you is private to the ISP. you can get your IP by seeing the router or log in to your ISP portal -> Data Usage -> Framed IP (It may not doing by all ISPs).

> Using this IP (10.1.X.X) you can access your computer remotely if the other computer is connected to the ISP which you're also connected.

System B(10.1.10.45) can be connected to System A 10.1.10.23(Server). They might be have a Common DNS (10.1.10.1)

I hope it helps you